# Creating a new array for eache iteration of the function call. AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, oop, function

so I have writing a function that returns objects on the stage and puts them into an array. and the function works fine until i call the function on more than one object name, meaning if im in the root class, and I call this function on object1 lets say it will add all the object one's from the stage, but if i call it on object2 it will throw an error, which makes some sense, i guess it means that it is not adding it to a unique array, but im not sure how to do that.

would it be a good idea to maybe make a multidimensional array? if that is the case would it be too slow?

here is the function code:

```
public function findObjects(objectName, objLocation, bVisible = false):Array{
    for (var i = 0; i < objLocation.numChildren; i++){
        var nObj=objLocation.getChildAt(i);
        if (nObj is objectName){
            // add to array and make invisible
            obj.push(nObj);
            nObj.visible=bVisible;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you ever get a error, post the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function findObjects(type:Class, target:DisplayObjectContainer, bVisible:Boolean=false):Array
{
    var out:Array = [];

    for(var i:int = 0; i<target.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var obj:DisplayObject = target.getChildAt(i);

        if(obj is type)
        {
            out.push(obj);
            obj.visible = bVisible;
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

And then based on your code, the implementation would probably be:

```
obj = findObjects(MovieClip, container);
```

Comment: so first off thank you very much for posting an answer to my question. I attempted to implement what you have given me, but i keep getting this error. 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type Class. here is how i'm calling this method in my main .as file. 
    `Blocks = MyBase.findObjects(Block,gamesprite); // block is the name of the object on the stage. and this function works 
// if i don't have another instance of it. 
 `    

`turret = MyBase.findObjects(turret, gamesprite);`

Comment: what if i defined the `var out:Array` to be type Class instead? can you do that?

Comment: That error suggests that you're parsing a variable which is of type `Array` as the first argument of `findObjects()`

Comment: And no, `out` is an Array that is created, filled and then returned by `findObjects()`

Comment: I think the only way it is of type array is if i call that method more than once, because then it adds two items to check for. that's just a thought.

Comment: So where is `turret` created and what type is it? Or is `turret` a name of a class you're looking for?

Comment: Okay so i got it to work, but I'm still hitting the same problem, it only works if i only call it once.
now here is something interesting, if i call one insistence of the function and then trace(theName.length) the first one outputs a actual array length, but the second one does not.

Comment: What happens if you call it twice without assigning the returned Array to anything?